WSL will not start ever since Windows 11 upgraded to 24H2
Windows 11 24h2 was installed on my PC this week.  Ever since, WSL will not start.

When I press any key to install WSL, I get an error "connection with the server could not be established":

I have rebooted the PC a number of times.
In control panel, programs and features, WSL and VM platform are checked.
How do I update WSL to the latest version?

So did you run the command to update WSL? Which WSL kernel do you have installed? Have you run the command to install WSL to see if that will work?

it is wsl 2.  running wsl.exe --update  from windows terminal, running as administrator, results in an error: "a connection with the server could not be established"

Are the necessary services for WSL running?

The connection error is likely a DNS issue

does being able to ping a domain name show that DNS is working?

Let’s rule out something obvious. Do you live in a nation where traffic is routinely blocked or prohibited?

I am in NJ.  Verizon is the ISP.   There are no issues using a browser.  The windows update window is not working on my PC since 24H2 also. I click the "check for updates" and the check never completes.   Also, the "turn windows features on and off" window never populates.
I posted this problem on the microsoft answers forum.  I will post their response here.
thanks,

I turned off windows defender firewall.  Same problem.

Please do not randomly enable and disable features.  It makes diagnostic impossible.  Windows Defender is not the reason for this behavior. Please enable it. So "turn windows features on and off" window never populates", suggests a WinSxS issue.

I have almost same issue at the moment. Ping works normally inside Powershell but when using WSL like ubuntu 22.04.5, then ping 8.8.8.8 and apt update not working. enter image description here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
